# Creating a new table in mongoid for has_and_belongs_to_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, mongoid

I just started to code in rails using mongoid ,previously I coded in sql,sqlite etc,Now Iam a bit confused between associations.like in sql when you want a has_and_belongs_to_many association between two models you do in such a way

for example

```
    class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
       has_and_belongs_to_many :subjects 
    end

    class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
       has_and_belongs_to_many :students
    end
```

and we create a new table as

```
rails g migration CreateJoinTableStudentSubject student subject
```

In our migration file we do like this

```
  def change
   create_table :students_subjects do |t|
    t.references :student
    t.references :subject
    t.timestamps
 end
```

end

now my question is is this neccesary to create a new table when using mongoid or der is a alternative way for doing this.plz help Iam new to mongoid and rails.thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to include some code into your classes like this:

```
class Student
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_and_belongs_to_many :subjects
end

class Subject
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_and_belongs_to_many :students
end
```

There is a great [documentation](https://mongoid.github.io/old/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#has_and_belongs_to_many) here.

Hope it will help you!